# How to parse xml MTOM response

Tags: python, r, xml, soap, mtom

I made some SOAP requests.

```
Content-Type request: application/soap+xml
Content-Type response: application/xop+xml
```

I am confused, I cant parse the response using common R/Python XML modules. I am looking for a solution in R and/or Python to parse following xml MTOM response:

`\r\n--uuid:5520e277-960f-444e-9c67-6c4e03b35919+id=4512484\r\nContent-ID: <http://tempuri.org/0>\r\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\r\nContent-Type: application/xop+xml;charset=utf-8;type=\"application/soap+xml\"\r\n\r\n<s:Envelope xmlns:s=\"http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope\" xmlns:a=\"http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing\"><s:Header><a:Action s:mustUnderstand=\"1\">http://CIS/BIR/PUBL/2014/07/IUslugaBIRzewnPubl/DaneSzukajPodmiotyResponse</a:Action></s:Header><s:Body><DaneSzukajPodmiotyResponse xmlns=\"http://CIS/BIR/PUBL/2014/07\"><DaneSzukajPodmiotyResult>&lt;root&gt;&#xD;\n  &lt;dane&gt;&#xD;\n    &lt;Regon&gt;010016565&lt;/Regon&gt;&#xD;\n    &lt;Nip&gt;5270103391&lt;/Nip&gt;&#xD;\n    &lt;StatusNip /&gt;&#xD;\n    &lt;Nazwa&gt;MICROSOFT SPÓŁKA Z OGRANICZONĄ ODPOWIEDZIALNOŚCIĄ&lt;/Nazwa&gt;&#xD;\n    &lt;Wojewodztwo&gt;MAZOWIECKIE&lt;/Wojewodztwo&gt;&#xD;\n    &lt;Powiat&gt;Warszawa&lt;/Powiat&gt;&#xD;\n    &lt;Gmina&gt;Włochy&lt;/Gmina&gt;&#xD;\n    &lt;Miejscowosc&gt;Warszawa&lt;/Miejscowosc&gt;&#xD;\n    &lt;KodPocztowy&gt;02-222&lt;/KodPocztowy&gt;&#xD;\n    &lt;Ulica&gt;Aleje Jerozolimskie&lt;/Ulica&gt;&#xD;\n    &lt;NrNieruchomosci&gt;195A&lt;/NrNieruchomosci&gt;&#xD;\n    &lt;NrLokalu /&gt;&#xD;\n    &lt;Typ&gt;P&lt;/Typ&gt;&#xD;\n    &lt;SilosID&gt;6&lt;/SilosID&gt;&#xD;\n    &lt;DataZakonczeniaDzialalnosci /&gt;&#xD;\n    &lt;MiejscowoscPoczty&gt;Warszawa&lt;/MiejscowoscPoczty&gt;&#xD;\n  &lt;/dane&gt;&#xD;\n&lt;/root&gt;</DaneSzukajPodmiotyResult></DaneSzukajPodmiotyResponse></s:Body></s:Envelope>\r\n--uuid:5520e277-960f-444e-9c67-6c4e03b35919+id=4512484--\r\n`

Comment: do you really get it with `&lt;` and `&gt;` ? How do you get it? Where is your code? maybe it needs only to change some setting in existing code.

Comment: or you can use `html.unescape( '&lt;text&gt;' )` to get `'<text>'` and then you have `XML`

Comment: I see other problem - you get `headers` and `body` as one string. Using common Python module `requests` or even standard `urllib` you should get `body` without `headers`. Now you have to split it on empty line - `\r\n\r\n`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.